# Change Table Size Prawn

Tags: ruby, report, prawn

Hi guys I'm doing a ruby ​​report using prawn! how can I change the size of the table?

**Code:**

```
require "prawn"
require "prawn/table"

logo=Dir.pwd+"/logo.jpg"

arr = ['a', 'aa', 'aaa', 'ddd', 'eee', 'fff']
arr2 = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff']
arr3 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

Prawn::Document.generate("rapportino.pdf") do
  move_down 10
  image logo,:width=>540,:height=>60
  move_down 30
  text "Ragione Sociale:   "+ARGV[0] 
  move_down 30
  text "Nome Cantiere:     "+ARGV[1]
  move_down 30
  text "Note:  "+ARGV[2]
  move_down 30
  table([
  ["Articolo - Risorsa", "Descrizione", "Quantita"],
  *[arr, arr2, arr3]
  .transpose
  ])
end
```

Comment: Why don't you go for rghost?

Comment: @Rajagopalan I've never used it! Anyway, do you know where the problem could be in the code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass options hash as a arg to `table()` specifying the columns width or a width.

`options = {column_widths:{ 0 => 125, 1 => 100 }, width: 225}`

In your example:

```
options = {column_widths:{ 0 => 125, 1 => 100 }, width: 225}
arr = ['a', 'aa', 'aaa', 'ddd', 'eee', 'fff']
arr2 = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff']
arr3 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

Prawn::Document.generate("rapportino.pdf") do
  move_down 10
  image logo,:width=>540,:height=>60
  move_down 30
  text "Ragione Sociale:   "+ARGV[0] 
  move_down 30
  text "Nome Cantiere:     "+ARGV[1]
  move_down 30
  text "Note:  "+ARGV[2]
  move_down 30
  table([
    ["Articolo - Risorsa", "Descrizione", "Quantita"],
    *[arr, arr2, arr3]
    .transpose
    ],options)
end
```

Comment: Thanks it's start

Comment: No problem @riki hope it helped a bit.